# How to create a bounce animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an app and on the front page I want the business logo to bounce and change. Further explanation:

The logo should be in the centre of the screen, bouncing up and down slightly, and changing between different images (other logos).

I have attempted to research into it and I found a script that allows me to do it with a button but I would want it to happen as soon as the app has loaded. If anyone has some suggestions or help, please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Force unwraps are generally bleh
let logos = [UIImage(named: "img1")!, UIImage(named: "img2")!, UIImage(named: "img3")!]

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0,
                   options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
                   animations: {
                    self.logo.center.y += 50
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

    logoTransition()
}

private func logoTransition() {
    UIView.transition(with: logo, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        let index = self.logos.firstIndex(of: self.logo.image!) ?? 0
        self.logo.image = self.getNextLogoImage(for: index)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: {
            self.logoTransition()
        })
    }
}

private func getNextLogoImage(for index: Int) -> UIImage {
    // Check if last index then go to beginning
    guard index != logos.count - 1 else {
        return logos[0]
    }

    return logos[index+1]
}
```

Where `view` is direct parentView of your logo image. I did not get "Change" part.

`options: [.autoreverse, .repeat]` are creating loop for bounce animation. As for changing logos - I was not really sure what do you mean, but to change image of ImageView different type of animation is needed - transition one. We have to loop that one manually by using recurrency in the competition block.

As for "want it to happen as soon as the app has loaded" - you need to place that code in viewDidAppear block.

Comment: do I put img1, img2, img3 in my assets folder? @Kamajabu

Comment: do you have a script that I can directly copy to my empty view controller to work? @Kamajabu

Comment: Yes, you need to add assets yourself, where "img1", "img2" etc. are names of assets. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AddingImages.html

This is basically 90% of code that needs to be in your viewController. Only thing left to do is to create logo UIImageView programitically or in storyboard and adding assets.

Comment: I did this then linked it to my view controller and I get the error message, "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'logo'" and "Use of unresolved identifier 'logo'" @Kamajabu

Comment: Most probably you did not create logo UIImageView and not linked it to ViewController. It seems that you are lacking some basic knowledge, so I recommend going through some guides like: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html

You can also create logo programitically and add constraints manually through
   lazy var logo: UIImageView =  UIImageView(), but I would not recommend it based on current discussion, as this is more complex solution.

Comment: I got this working thank you! However, it displays img2 as the first image. How do I get it to display img1 first? @Kamajabu

Comment: You can do it by calling self.logo.image = logos[0] eg. in viewDidLoad, and if you did that it's possible it starts transition right away so you can nest  logoTransition() in its own 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute) so first transition gets delayed a bit and don't go stright to second logo :)  

Glad to hear it works for you! Feel free to approve this answer as correct one then ;)